# mpd mpc query language

Tags: mpd

I can't figure out how to properly query `mpd` using `mpc`.

For example: I know how to list all albums

```
mpc list album
```

But I want to get more than the name.

How can I query `mpd` for album, path, artist, track number, duration and so on? Preferably in one query but multiple queries are ok as well.

I tried to read the `mpc` man page and the official documentation of `mpd` but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpc` does not (as of this writing, v0.27-1) have any commands that give you all the metadata for a song, identified by uri. It's surprising that it doesn't, but it doesn't.

The MPD [communication protocol](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/protocol/command_reference.html), however, does return full information about each song.

If I issue `mpc current` I only get this response:

```
Afro Celt Sound System - Release
```

However, if I send the MPD (not MPC) command `currentsong` then I get this response from MPD:

```
file: gavin/Compilations/Volume 2 _ Release/01 Release.m4a
Last-Modified: 2005-03-02T14:16:51Z
Artist: Afro Celt Sound System
Album: Volume 2 : Release
Title: Release
Track: 1/11
Genre:World
Date: 1999
Composer: Simon Emerson, James McNally, Iarla O Lionaird, Martin Russell & Sinead O'Connor/Sinéad O'Connor
Disc: 1/1
Time: 456
Pos: 0
Id: 53616
```

If I send the MPD command `playlistid 49312` I get this response:

```
file: gavin/ATB/Future Memories/16 Missing 1.m4a
Last-Modified: 2013-11-17T21:14:43Z
Artist: ATB
Album: Future Memories
Title: Missing
Track: 16/29
Genre: Dance
Date: 2009-05-01T07:00:00Z
Composer: Tracey Thorn & Ben Watt
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: ATB
Time: 256
Pos: 10
Id: 49312
```

If I send the command `search file surfing` I get this response (different songs are delimited by a new `file:`):

```
file: doza/Air/06 Surfing On a Rocket.m4a
Last-Modified: 2015-11-20T15:56:00Z
Time: 223
Artist: Air
Album: Talkie Walkie
Title: Surfing On a Rocket
Track: 6/10
Genre: Electronic
Date: 2004-01-26T08:00:00Z
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: Air
file: gavin/Air/Surfing On a Rocket EP/06 Surfing on a rocket (remixed by Joakim).m4a
Last-Modified: 2015-01-13T15:31:39Z
Time: 393
Artist: Air
Album: Surfing On a Rocket EP
Title: Surfing on a rocket (remixed by Joakim)
Track: 6/7
Genre: Dance
Date: 2004-09-10T07:00:00Z
Composer: Jean-Benoit Dunckel & Nicolas Godin
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: Air
file: gavin/The Beach Boys/Greatest Surfing Songs!/02 Little Deuce Coupe.mp3
Last-Modified: 2009-09-10T04:32:49Z
Time: 111
Artist: The Beach Boys
Title: Little Deuce Coupe
Album: Greatest Surfing Songs!
Track: 2
Genre: Sunshine Pop
```

And if I send the MPD command `listplaylistinfo Thump`, I get this response:

```
file: gavin/Muse/The 2nd Law (Deluxe Version)/02 Madness.m4a
Last-Modified: 2013-11-17T22:30:54Z
Artist: Muse
Album: The 2nd Law (Deluxe Version)
Title: Madness
Track: 2/13
Genre: Alternative
Date: 2012-10-01T07:00:00Z
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: Muse
Time: 280
file: gavin/U2/The Best Of 1990-2000/15 Numb (New Mix).mp3
Last-Modified: 2003-09-24T14:31:05Z
Artist: U2
Title: Numb (New Mix)
Album: The Best Of 1990-2000
Track: 15/16
Date: 2002
Genre: Rock
Composer: U2
Time: 264
file: gavin/Massive Attack/Mezzanine/03 Teardrop.m4a
Last-Modified: 2012-09-05T19:38:14Z
Artist: Massive Attack
Album: Mezzanine
Title: Teardrop
Track: 3/11
Genre: Electronic
Date: 1998-04-20T07:00:00Z
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: Massive Attack
Time: 331
file: gavin/Massive Attack/Mezzanine/01 Angel.m4a
Last-Modified: 2012-09-05T19:38:17Z
Artist: Massive Attack
Album: Mezzanine
Title: Angel
Track: 1/11
Genre: Electronic
Date: 1998-04-20T07:00:00Z
Disc: 1/1
AlbumArtist: Massive Attack
Time: 380
file: gavin/Eels/Shrek 2/07 I Need Some Sleep.mp3
Last-Modified: 2005-01-14T21:24:25Z
Artist: Eels
Title: I Need Some Sleep
Album: Shrek 2
Track: 7/14
Date: 2004
Genre: Soundtrack
Time: 147
```

I personally use the [`ruby-mpd`](https://github.com/archSeer/ruby-mpd) library to provide a convenient interface to communicating with MPD, in a rich, full-featured way.

Answer (score 5):

```
 import audioscrobbler
import mpd
import random
import time


lastsong = {}

def timer_control():
    get_similar()
    time.sleep(10)
    timer_control()

def get_similar():
    audioscrobbler
    client = mpd.MPDClient()
    client.connect("localhost", 6600)
    mpdstatus = client.status()
    prevsonginfo = client.currentsong()
    global lastsong
    if mpdstatus['state'] == "stop": return
    if prevsonginfo == lastsong: return 

    lastsong = prevsonginfo
    similarartists = ""
    song = prevsonginfo
    #if not song: break #No song, do nothing
    prevartist = song['artist']

    # Is the info already cached?
    similar_cache = {}
    if similar_cache.has_key(prevartist):
        similarartists = similar_cache[prevartist]
    else:
        #Not cached so fetch from Audioscrobbler
        try:
            similarartists = [artist.name for artist in audioscrobbler.AudioScrobblerQuery(artist=prevartist).similar()]
            # Cache search results and save some time next search
            similar_cache[prevartist] = similarartists
        except audioscrobbler.AudioScrobblerError:
            similar_cache[prevartist] = None # Empty cache
            return # Do nothing!

    if not similarartists: return # Empty list

    # Split list in half and sort upper half
    # this means good matches will have priority
    # but makes sure artist A does not always result in artist B
    half_idx = len(similarartists)/2
    upperhalf = similarartists[:half_idx]
    lowerhalf = similarartists[half_idx:]
    random.shuffle(upperhalf)
    artistlist = upperhalf
    artistlist.extend(lowerhalf)
    # Try each artist in order
    for artist in artistlist:
        try:
            print "Trying:",artist
            songs = client.search("artist", artist)
            if not songs: continue
            selected_song = random.sample(songs, 1)[0]
            client.add(selected_song['file'])
            print "Added", selected_song['title'],"by",selected_song['artist']
            # Delete old song from playlist?
            break
        except mpd.MPDError, e:
            print "MPDError", e.message
            continue
        except ValueError, e:
            print "ValueError:",e.message
            continue


timer_control()
```

follow this article for more info
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=49765
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/mpc.1.html